# Fallo al acceder a matrices dinamicas c++

Tags: c++

Buenas tardes. Llevo toda la tarde dando vueltas a la revision de mi codigo puesto que he estado usando el DEV C++ y me ha compilado una matriz cuya declaracion tenia variables, sin embargo, yo sabia que eso no podia ser y al pasarlo a otros compiladores como el del Visual Studio salta un error.

Tras leer documentacion de como crear matrices dinamicas, ya no me acordaba, y con el proposito de que el codigo corriera en cualquier compilador, he implementado lo que he leido en mi codigo pero no consigo que haga las primeras operaciones en el primer paso y no se que esta ocurriendo (una vez solucionado esto seria una iteracion de lo mismo)

Dejo el codigo por aqui por si me podeis echar una mano pero antes de nada os explico de forma resumida porque quiero usar las matrices dinamicas. Dependiendo de unos datos de entrada. Este programa generara una matriz de salida siempre de la misma forma una cantidad ingente de filas (pueden ser desde 100 hasta por ejemplo 10.000, a partir de ese numero ya seria un poco exagerado pero tampoco seria descabellado obtener calculos con 30.000, 50.000... ptos por eso necesito el calculo dinamico) y solo tres columnas (que coincide con la tipica base canonica x, y z)

A partir de "dimensions" es cuando empiezo a preparar la matriz dinamica o en la linea de este comentario //Creacion de los punteros para crear las matrices.

He leido tambien sobre la libreria vector pero no se tanto C++ para como usarla y ademas tambien he leido que es unidimensional. Se que con punteros se puede hacer lo que quiero porque lo he hecho hace años pero ya no me acuerdo.
Un saludo y gracias.

EDITO CON UN PROGRAMA MAS SIMPLE Y ENTENDIBLE PARA CUALQUIERA QUE PUEDA TENER ESTA DUDA EN EL FUTURO:

```
#include "iostream"
#include "cstdlib"
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int i;
    int a = 4;
    int crea1=4;
    double aux1[3] = { 1,5,7 };
    double **p1;
    p1 = new double *[a]; //Numeros de filas
    **for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)** **Aqui es donde esta el error**
    {
        p1[i] = new double[3]; //Numero de columnas
    }
    for (i = 0; i<a; i++)
    {
        p1[i][0] = aux1[0];
        p1[i][1] = aux1[1];
        p1[i][2] = aux1[2];
    }
    delete[] p1;
    cin.get();
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: podrias poner el error del compilador?

Comment: Cuando tengas más experiencia te darás cuenta de que por la pinta del código presentado puedes deducir con bastante precisión si una persona se lo ha currado o no. Por otro lado, los errores tontos son los más complicados de encontrar porque se esconden en partes que asumimos que son correctas. La mejor forma de encontrarlos es tirar de depurador y de testing (nada mejor que una batería de pruebas sobre cada función para encontrar la que no funciona como es debido)... al final todo se basa en la experiencia.

Comment: Un problema importante de los códigos largos es que suelen tener problemas no documentados en la pregunta y es facil que dicha pregunta se acabe convirtiendo en un partido de tenis (alguien responde y soluciona un problema pero aparece otro error y el OP edita la pregunta o pone comentarios... se corrige y aparece un tercer error y vuelta a empezar...). Hay que saber acotar las preguntas para que las respuestas tengan sentido.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Matriz p1[crea1][3];
```

Efectivamente esto no es legal en C++. Esta declaración se corresponde a un VLA (**V**ariable **L**ength **A**rray), característica contemplada en el estándar de C no así en el de C++.

Ahora bien, tu alternativa tiene una laguna importante

```
double** p1;
p1 = new double *[crea1];
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
//              ^ AQUI!!!!
{
    p1[i] = new double[3];
}
```

Ese `3` debería ser `crea1` ya que como bien has indicado unas pocas líneas atras...

```
++crea1; // 3+1=4 <<--- OJO 4, no 3!!!!
```

El no inicializar esa cuarta fila es lo que hace que el programa casque aquí:

```
//ERROR salta en el compilador aqui
for (i = 0; i<crea1; i++)
{
    escvec(i, DES, aux1);
    sumavector(ptoi, aux1, aux1);
    p1[i][0] = aux1[0]; // <<--- 
    p1[i][1] = aux1[1];
    p1[i][2] = aux1[2];
}
```

Ya que cuando `i==crea1-1==3` el programa intenta acceder a un puntero no válido.